# Working with `mysqli_insert_id` in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a question. If for example 20 people would register on my site at the same time. And in each register I need to get their id using

```
mysqli_insert_id()
```

Would that script, take their id correctly? or it can take id of others?

Comment: MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT and related features work as expected.

Comment: The result of the `mysqli_insert_id()` are relative to the connection. So each script has its own connection and therefore you will get the right answer in each of the 20 connections

Comment: So, it will be ok? Sorry for double question

Comment: a mysqli_ question closed with a mysql_ one; nice. And totally contradicts the question here and the dupe *"Is mysql_insert_id safe to use?"* - hello??

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks. Now I understood.

Comment: Fred -ii- If it`s not, what will be better to use?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Closed with the correct Dup

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - that makes more "common sense" ;-)